# Dummit and Foote 6.1.2

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, nilpotent-groups

Let $P$ be a finite nilpotent group.

We want to show that every proper subgroup of $P$ is a proper subgroup of its normalizer in $P$.

I was following the solution. But there are certain parts I didn't understand.

---

Suppose $H$ is a proper subgroup of $P$.

We know that it's always the case that if $H$ is a subgroup of $P$, then $H \le N_p(H)$.

We will show that if $H \ne P$, then $H \ne N_p(H)$.

Since $P$ is nilpotent, by definition using upper central series, $Z_i(P)=P$ for some $i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Since $H$ is proper, $Z_{i-1}(P) \subseteq H \subsetneq Z_i(P)$.

Let $x\in Z_i(P) - H$. We will show that $x\in N_p(H)$.

Let $h \in H$. Then we have $[x,h^{-1}] = x^{-1}hxh^{-1} \in Z_{i-1}(P) \subseteq H$.

Thus, $x^{-1}hx \in H$.

---

Now here are my questions:

1. Why it's that case that $Z_{i-1}(P) \subseteq H \subsetneq Z_i(P)$? I feel like that this has something to do with this theorem below.
   [image]

But I still don't really see why $Z_{i-1} \subseteq H \subsetneq Z_i(P)$, where we can't have something like $Z_{i-2}(P) \subseteq H \subseteq Z_{i-1}(P) \subsetneq Z_i(P)$.

2. Why do we have $x^{-1}hxh^{-1} \in Z_{i-1}(P)$?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text. Also, please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition we have $1= Z_0(P)\le H$. Hence, there exists a largest $i\ge 1$ such that $Z_{i-1}(P)\le H$. Note that we do not necessarily have $Z_i(P)=P$ (I don't know where you got this from). Take $x\in Z_i(P)\setminus H$. By definition $x Z_{i-1}(P)\in Z(P/Z_{i-1}(P))$. It follows that $xHx^{-1}/Z_{i-1}(P)=H/Z_{i-1}(P)$ and $xHx^{-1}=H$. Therefore, $x\in N_P(H)$.